# Switch Datasource on run time (based on headers) in Hibernate session factory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have 2 instances of DB. Each for a different client. This is my hibernate config class :

```
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.mhycomoant.test.model"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings","false");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return transactionManager;
    }

   }
```

Here is my Dao class

```
    @Repository
    @Transactional()
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }


    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
    this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable save(Person wt) {
        return getCurrentSession().save(wt);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> list() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        //Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    //  List<WalletTransaction> personList = session.createQuery("from person").list();
    //  session.close();
    //  return personList;
    }
```

How can I switch the DB's at the runtime?

Comment: Why aren't you creating multiple data sources?

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha Shall I read header value in this config class and use if else to switch? Is there a cleaner way? Also, I guess connection would be made at startup, How would switch at runtime be made?

Comment: if the connections are made at startup and pooled then active connections will be used and the code would run swiftly rather than creating the connection when the requests are received. Also, connection pooling will not be maintained properly if the data source is reconfigured based on every request.

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha Okay but how do I switch the dabs? Lets say in my Dao class, how does hibernate know that which DB to use

Comment: if there are multiple datasources then there will be multiple sessionFactories. There will be different methods in `HibernateConfiguration` class for particular connections and session factory. You can inject them into your `PersonDaoImpl` then.

Comment: Point is where do I decide which factory to use!

Comment: Firstly, the number of databases/connection factories depend on the number of clients! Shouldn't there be an alternative approach for it?

Comment: Totally agree. Thats why I asked is there a cleaner way for this? Would appreciate your inputs on this.

Comment: Have you thought about using the same DB for all clients with one or two extra column differentiating the client?

Comment: Umm that is not possible. I have to use a different DB.

Comment: Suppose you've two clients, one is small and another one is way bigger than the previous one. Don't you think that providing one separate DB to a small candidate would be an overkill?

Comment: True that but in my case both the clients are giants and I can't have same DB. Thats why  I need two.